# Calling Multiple Groovy Functions in Mule

Tags: groovy, mule

I have an external groovy file that has 3 functions that are used throughout the application. They are scripts that are not like the simple examples that are used in the examples. How can I call specific functions from within a scripting component? For example if I have a functions such as the following in a file myscript.groovy:

```
   def convert(valueList){
      valueList.each{
         //.... do some conversion
       }
   }

   def convert(valueList, dataUsage){
      valueList.each{
         //.... do some conversion
       }
   }
   ///I want to be able to call it from a script component like below:
   <script:component>
      <script:script engine="groovy" file="myscript.groovy">
        // How can I call the convert methods here...

      </script:script>
   <.script:component>
```

How can I call the different functions from within the mule app from script components like the one shown above?